# Content position Importance

Tags: seo, usability, ux

I have a site which has just external news links, I also have a few sentences to describe the page. What is a good position for the page description in terms of UX and bots perspective?

These are the two options I can consider:

[image: option 1, with h1 followed by descriptive paragraphs]

[image: Option 2, descriptive paragraphs on sidebar]

Another thing to consider also is that, it is a responsive layout which means the sidebar goes right to the bottom on smaller screens.

Comment: It is a matter of opinion. However, based upon what you said about a mobile or responsive site, it seems like your first example makes the most sense. You have to think of the user first and search engines second. As well, search engines want to see valuable content first especially in mobile sites.

Comment: I've used the first one and it seems to have been a positive change thus far.

Comment: Good! I am glad. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a Google point of view, you want your content above the fold (before users need to scroll):

> As we’ve mentioned previously, we’ve heard complaints from users that if they click on a result and it’s difficult to find the actual content, they aren’t happy with the experience. Rather than scrolling down the page past a slew of ads, users want to see content right away. So sites that don’t have much content “above-the-fold” can be affected by this change.

https://search.googleblog.com/2012/01/page-layout-algorithm-improvement.html

Although this Google update was targeting sites with adds above the fold, the wording above seems to give the impression that any sites with any content not appearing before a scroll may be affected.

If having just a h1 and a bunch of links pushed any content below the fold, I would go for the first option.

You could also do [A/B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) with different layoutd to see which results in the best [UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience_design)